# Setup phpmyadmin with PHP 8.2?

Tags: phpmyadmin

After following the tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04

I've been getting a seemingly endless amount of errors with phpmyadmin. I fix one then move onto the next but I'm wondering if it just isn't compatible yet or if I set it up incorrectly. The tutorial mentions a list of packages to be installed and to refer to your version of php for the correct pages. I cannot find that list for PHP 8.2.

The current list of packages is:
phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json php-curl

In which I changed php-mbstring to php8.2-mbstring and left the others. After this did not work I tried changing the others to php8.2 versions to no avail:
phpmyadmin php8.2-mbstring php8.2-zip php8.2-gd php-json php8.2-curl
Note: It appears that it updates the libraries to 8.2 automatically when applicable if installing with the regular names.

I've added parenthesis to certain functions in phpmyadmin, overrode/updated mbstring due to the new deprecation notices with PHP 8.2, commented out lines that are being called more than once (when they aren't supposed to be), etc.

It is now giving the errors such as "Cannot redeclare PMA_sprites()" and "Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array"

I'm done solving errors even though there are more and I'm going to assume that either a. It's not compatible or b. I'm installing the wrong libraries. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. These errors occur when I visit mysite/phpmyadmin and come from the error.log.

Comment: Different errors, same effect. Started with some mysqli problems. After reinstall of phpmyadmin I get a lot of deprecation notices on Login page and empty page after login (tried different users). Error log tells me access to table mysql.user was denied which I should not need. So anyone got it running with PHP8.2?

Comment: Ok, got it mostly running. For my trouble with rights I put a `try {} catch(Throwable $t){ return false;}` around the query in DatabaseInterface:tryQuery(). For all the error messages I went to the given lines from error log and fixed them. Was trivial in nearly all cases so far. Still saw things that should not be allowed. Did not find PMA_sprites(), but maybe you need something like `if (!is_array($var)) $var = [$var];`

Comment: I don't think the current version of phpMyAdmin (5.2.1) is compatible with PHP 8+. Their [downloads page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) lists 5.2.1 to have PHP 7.2 compatibility and their future version 6.0 will add PHP 8.1 compatibility.